# How can I hang a shelf off of existing screws in brick wall?

Tags: screws, brick, hanging

Recently moved into an apartment, and setting it up.
I need to hang a projector and a video game console off of a brick wall in the home.

Ideally, because it's an apartment, I don't alter the wall.

There are 2 existing screws coming out of the brick - screwed into the brick itself. There seems to be some plastic anchor supporting them. The screws are 5ft (1.5m) apart, come out about half an inch, and the "shelf" needs to come out about 12-18in (30-45cm) and support ~15lbs (~7kg) of weight at most.

Is this possible? If so, how? I have woodworking tools and patience, but not much know-how. My intention here is to make a make-shift shelf cutting up wood and hanging it however I can. Alternatively, happy to buy something if I can find shelving with mounts exactly 5ft apart.

[image: wall]
[image: screw]

If not, what's another no- or low-damage way of hanging such a shelf (minimum 12in depth, 3ft wide)?

Comment: We do not know what kind of shelf you have and what is required to mount it.

Comment: My intention here is to make a make-shift shelf cutting up wood boards. Will clarify, thanks.

Comment: There is no way to adequately support 12-18" shelves on those two screws. It's more about the measurement than the weight

Comment: I agree with ack , 5’ long shelf would need more supports I would say at least 2 more triangle brackets for a total of 4 with 2 screws each.

Comment: I would use keyhole hanger brackets like [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/OOK-20-lb-Large-Keyhole-Hangers-2-Pack-50236/100018911) mounted to vertical supports to which your shelf would be attached. Also, those screws could easily support a 2' long shelf, but as others have said 5' may be a bit long, unless you keep it very light.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use those screws since you have no way of knowing how they were installed.  However, I would suggest you look into brick hanging clips (use Google to find them). These are made of metal and are designed to grip the bricks. No holes are required. You made need a number of them depending on the weight of your stuff. I have used them to hang pictures on brick walls.

Comment: I've seen these - my concern here is that the edges of the brick aren't quite exposed - the mortar, for most of the wall, is protruding further than the brick.